# Do not select grouped items in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Supposing that I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT items, COUNT(customers)
FROM sales
GROUP BY items
HAVING COUNT(customers) > 1;
```

Is there somehow to do this operation and query only the `item` column?

I don't want to include the count of customers in my result, and I can't use as an aggregation for `WHERE`

```
SELECT items
FROM sales
WHERE COUNT(customers) > 1;
```

Of course that this query above will throw me an error, because I'm using an aggregation inside `WHERE` and that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT items
FROM sales
GROUP BY items
HAVING COUNT(customers) > 1;
```